# как запустить в aiogram две функции выполняемые в бесконечном цикле

Tags: python, aiogram, асинхронность, aiogram-3.x

Как при запуске бота (на Aiogram) запустить в бесконечном цикле две асин.функции ?

```py
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from aiogram import types, F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command

from aiogram import Router
router = Router()
# _______________
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

import sys
import os

Token = 'test:xx12'

# Test new async fucns
async def Alert_notify_price_levels():
    now_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'start Alert_notify_price_levels: {now_time}')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    now_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'end Alert_notify_price_levels {now_time}')
    return 'func1'
    
    
async def find_support():
    cur_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'start find_support {cur_time}')
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    cur_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'end find_support {cur_time}')
    return 'func2'


# _______________________________________________________


@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start_handler(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer("Привет! Я помогу тебе узнать твой ID, просто отправь мне любое сообщение")


@router.message()
async def message_handler(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(f"Твой ID: {msg.from_user.id}")


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=Token, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    while True:

        # ---> \n как сделать чтобы эти функции заново запустились
        res = await asyncio.gather(find_support(), Alert_notify_price_levels())    # get all return values of two this async_functions   
        logger.info(f'{res=}')
        
        dp.include_router(router)
        await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
        await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Зачем цикл в функций main? В функциях find_support, Alert_notify_price_levels пристроить цикл?

Comment: а чтобы две функции заново запустились как то так :) , у меня был похожий бот на старой версии aiogram 2.x. ) , а эта aiogram версии 3.0 и там на старой версии был подобный функционал ... использовал while true в main. А как сделать чтобы сами эти функции запустились и работали бесконечно при запуске бота / или работали параллельно боту?

Comment: А что вам мешает поместить цикл в код самих функций?

Comment: не знаю , мне почему то кажется что эти функции нужно запустить именно вместе с ботом ;) так как ранее имел подобный функционал и все устраивало меня